# Plot total and subset of data side by side in facet_grid heatmap using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data contains 4 columns. I can plot all the data together and subset of data but I am not sure how to put both these dataframes together in one figure. In each facet I want to put a column for total on the left and a column for subset on the right. Sample figure[image]

```
ID  A   B   date
1   A   AB  4/1/2020
2   A   AB  4/14/2020
3   B   CA  4/13/2020
4   B   DF  4/14/2020
5   B   CA  4/21/2020
6   B   CB  4/23/2020
7   C   CB  3/16/2020
8   C   CB  3/26/2020
9   C   CB  3/30/2020
10  C   CB  4/1/2020
11  C   DF  4/8/2020
12  C   DF  4/17/2020
13  C   DF  4/13/2020
14  D   DF  4/1/2020
15  E   AB  4/20/2020
16  F   AB  3/27/2020
17  F   CA  4/20/2020
18  F   CD  4/20/2020

d<-read.table("mydata.txt", header=TRUE)
fig1 <- d %>% group_by(A,B) %>%
  summarize(Count = n())
p<-ggplot(fig1, aes(x=B, y=A)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=fig1$Count),  width=0.1) + facet_grid(~fig1$B, scale="free_x") + geom_text(aes(label = Count)) + labs(x="Count", y= "A", fill ="Value", Title= "Data summary") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "dark red") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
##subset based on date
monthly_data<-subset(d, date> "2020-04-51")
fig2 <- monthly_data %>% group_by(A,B) %>%
+     summarize(Count = n())
> p1<-ggplot(fig2, aes(x=B, y=A)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=fig2$Count),  width=0.1) + facet_grid(~fig2$B, scale="free_x")+ geom_text(aes(label = Count)) + labs(x="Count", y= "A", fill ="Value", Title= "subset") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "dark red") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your total data and your subset data into a single data.frame and then plot the result

```
combined <- rbind(
  cbind(fig1, from="total"),
  cbind(fig2, from="subset"))

ggplot(combined, aes(x=from, y=A)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Count),  width=0.1) + 
  facet_grid(~B, scale="free_x") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Count)) + 
  labs(x="Count", y= "A", fill ="Value", Title= "subset") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "dark red") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Test with

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
d <- read.table(text="
ID  A   B   date
1   A   AB  4/1/2020
2   A   AB  4/14/2020
3   B   CA  4/13/2020
4   B   DF  4/14/2020
5   B   CA  4/21/2020
6   B   CB  4/23/2020
7   C   CB  3/16/2020
8   C   CB  3/26/2020
9   C   CB  3/30/2020
10  C   CB  4/1/2020
11  C   DF  4/8/2020
12  C   DF  4/17/2020
13  C   DF  4/13/2020
14  D   DF  4/1/2020
15  E   AB  4/20/2020
16  F   AB  3/27/2020
17  F   CA  4/20/2020
18  F   CD  4/20/2020", header=T)

fig1 <- d %>% group_by(A,B) %>%
  summarize(Count = n())
monthly_data <- subset(d, date> "2020-04-51")
fig2 <- monthly_data %>% group_by(A,B) %>%
       summarize(Count = n())
```

Comment: bind_rows throws an error: Error: Argument 2 must be length 51, not 1

Comment: @akang What version of dplyr are you using? I just changed it to use the base `rbind` and `cbind` functions, maybe that will work for you

Comment: dplyr ver 0.8.3. I get the same error with cbind and rbind. Could it be because of different number of rows in two data frames?

Comment: `rbind` doesn't require that both data.frames have the same number of rows. Are you sure you are running the same code in the question above? And there aren't any other errors? It works fine for me. I added all the code I ran in a fresh R session

Comment: Yes, running the same code. cbind seems to be the problem.  I changed the code just to test. Works fine If I do combined <- rbind(
    cbind(fig1,fig1)) but wont work if combined <- rbind(
    cbind(fig1,fig2))

Comment: @akang Yeah, `cbind(fig1,fig2)` will never work because you can only cbind things if they have the same number of rows. That's why I didn't do that. I used `cbind` to add a new column to each data.frame and then combined them using `rbind`. Are you not using the code exactly as I wrote it?

Comment: I am using the exact code that you wrote but it doesn't work. I appreciate your time and help

Comment: Do you get an error just from running `cbind(fig1, from="total")`? If not, what does `dim(cbind(fig1, from="total"))` return? Then what does `dim(cbind(fig2, from="subset"))` return?

Comment: Ran it with my full data and here is the error. Error: Argument 2 must be length 51, not 1 ; Error: Argument 2 must be length 31, not 1. I tried merge and it seems to work merge(data.frame(fig1, row.names=NULL), data.frame(fig2, row.names=NULL),
by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]

Comment: Merge is not what I am looking for though.

Comment: What version of R are you using? What does `class(fig1)` and `dim(fig1)` return? What about `environment(cbind)`?

Comment: R version 3.5.2 ; "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"; "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"; <environment: namespace:base>

Comment: Well, you are using an older version of dplyr and R that I don't have easy access to test with. Maybe there was a bug in it. Does `mutate(fig1, from="total")` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224995/discussion-between-akang-and-mrflick).